# AS3 AIR mobile urlloader progress bar

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an app (for iOS and Android) which has the ability for users to select an image from the cameraroll or take an image using the cameraui. After selecting the image it is then uploaded to a server using urlloader and urlrequestwrapper class. This all works great but I need to display a percentage uploaded progress text/bar to the user but having real trouble finding a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Listen ProgressEvent.PROGRESS:

```
var loader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressHandler);

function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace(e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal);
}
```

But notice, that your server has to support dispatching progress event for flash. Read the same problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99319/grab-a-progressevent-from-a-post-upload-in-as3)